# Why is this constructor failing to load in Code Igniter?

Tags: codeigniter, constructor

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {
    function Blog() {
        parent::CI_Controller();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a constructor in Code Igniter for my class 'Blog' and the above code is giving me a fatal error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   CI_Controller::CI_Controller() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mysites\blog\application\controllers\blog.php
>   on line 5

How do I fix this?

(I'm going through a online video tutorial on the official code igniter website but I think the tutorial is about 2 years out of date as some of the things are not working when I follow them exactly as shown in the video, this being one of them - the link to the video is [here](http://codeigniter.com/tutorials/watch/intro/) - I encounter this problem towards the end of the tutorial about 8 minutes in)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It should be this...

```
<?php
class Blog extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

}
```

The tutorial you are probably going through is based on 1.7.2 which had a core of php4 which did not use the php5 `__construct()` method of building Class constructors.  Codeigniter 2.0.0 has a php5 core and uses it.

Comment: thank you very much, yes the tutorial is based on 1.7.2 while I'm trying to work with the newer 2.0.0 version. You solution fixed the problem perfectly!

Comment: That's exactly what I needed too! Tahnk you a lot. You saved me a lot of time ;-)